# Error while adding calculated field in Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have created a pivot table and I want to add a calculated field. I have written some lines of code trying to make it work but it keeps saying unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class. the error appears in line

```
With .PivotFields("Diff")
```

The lines of code related to adding the new calculated field are below

```
.CalculatedFields.Add "Diff", "= ('Monthly Forecasted Cost'- 'Actual Cost')"

 With .PivotFields("Diff")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Position = 11
 End With
```

Comment: You appear to have a stray space after the equals and before ('Monthly Forecasted Cost'

Are you sure the field is actually being added and not failing silently on the .Add?

Comment: @HarassedDad I am not sure whether it dies ! Possibly it’s the formula too , but I deduct the pivot fields correctly , as the names that I use are actually the names of the fields and the formula seems to be correct in terms of commas, etc ... any idea what could be wrong with the formula ?

Comment: Fire up the macro recorder, add the field manually, then review the code to see how it differs from what you've posted.